# column headers in select Union query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to select query like the following example :

```
Select name,
       SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM'),'01',PRICE)) JAN_12,
       SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM'),'02',PRICE)) FEB_12
 from price_list_LastYear

 UNION ALL

 Select name,
        SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM'),'01',PRICE)) JAN_11,
        SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM'),'02',PRICE)) FEB_11
  from price_list_TwoLastYear.
```

When I execute the query, In my column header I get name, `JAN_12`, `FEB_12`.
I want to combine my results like : name, `JAN_11`, `JAN_12`, `FEB_11`,`FEB_12`.

Comment: Then don't use a `union` or `union all` operator. That's not how they work. Use the right tool for the right job. [Try something.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You need pivot function or use joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT A.*, B,JAN_11, B.FEB_11 FROM (
Select name,
       SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM'),'01',PRICE)) JAN_12,
       SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM'),'02',PRICE)) FEB_12
 from price_list_LastYear
 Group By Name) A

 LEFT OUTER JOIN (

 Select name,
        SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM'),'01',PRICE)) JAN_11,
        SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM'),'02',PRICE)) FEB_11
  from price_list_TwoLastYear
  Group By Name) B ON A.name = B.Name
```

Or

```
Select name,
SUM(CASE WHEN Yr = '11' THEN DECODE(Mnth,'01',PRICE) ELSE NULL END) JAN_11,
SUM(CASE WHEN Yr = '12' THEN DECODE(Mnth,'01',PRICE) ELSE NULL END) JAN_12,
SUM(CASE WHEN Yr = '11' THEN DECODE(Mnth,'02',PRICE) ELSE NULL END) FEB_11,
SUM(CASE WHEN Yr = '12' THEN DECODE(Mnth,'02',PRICE) ELSE NULL END) FEB_12
from 
(

 SELECT '12' As yr, name, TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM') Mnth, Price
 FROM price_list_LastYear
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '11' As yr, name, TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM') Mnth, Price
 FROM price_list_TwoLastYear
)
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT P1.name,
       SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(P1.Datee,'MM'),'01',P1.PRICE)) JAN_12,
       SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(P1.Datee,'MM'),'02',P1.PRICE)) FEB_12,
       SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(P2.Datee,'MM'),'01',P2.PRICE)) JAN_11,
       SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(P2.Datee,'MM'),'02',P2.PRICE)) FEB_11
FROM price_list_LastYear P1
   JOIN price_list_TwoLastYear P2
     ON P1.nmae = P2.nmae
GROUP BY P1.nmae
```

If same name doesn't exists in both tables try this:

```
SELECT N.name,
   SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(P1.Datee,'MM'),'01',P1.PRICE)) JAN_12,
   SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(P1.Datee,'MM'),'02',P1.PRICE)) FEB_12,
   SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(P2.Datee,'MM'),'01',P2.PRICE)) JAN_11,
   SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(P2.Datee,'MM'),'02',P2.PRICE)) FEB_11
FROM
(
    SELECT name FROM price_list_LastYear
    UNION 
    SELECT name FROM price_list_TwoLastYear
) N
LEFT JOIN price_list_LastYear P1
   ON N.nmae = P1.name
LEFT JOIN price_list_TwoLastYear P2
   ON N.nmae = P2.name
GROUP BY N.name
```

Comment: If sane name doesn't exists in both tables, then see @bluefeet answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the `name` does not exist in both tables, then it might be difficult to use a `JOIN`. So here is a version using `UNION ALL` and then applying an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to transform the data to columns:

```
SELECT name,
  sum(case when Month = 'JAN_12' then price else 0 end) JAN_12,
  sum(case when Month = 'FEB_12' then price else 0 end) FEB_12,
  sum(case when Month = 'JAN_11' then price else 0 end) JAN_11,
  sum(case when Month = 'FEB_11' then price else 0 end) FEB_11
FROM
(
  Select name,
    PRICE,
    case 
      when TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM') = '01' Then 'JAN_12'
      when TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM') = '02' Then 'FEB_12' End Month
  from price_list_LastYear
  WHERE TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM') in ('01', '02')
  UNION ALL
  Select name,
    PRICE,
    case 
      when TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM') = '01' Then 'JAN_11'
      when TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM') = '02' Then 'FEB_11' End Month
  from price_list_TwoLastYear
  WHERE TO_CHAR(Datee,'MM') in ('01', '02')
) src
GROUP BY name
```